# Is good to have swfuploader for image/video uploads?

Tags: php, flash, swfupload

We are working in real estate project, there we have image and video uploads in many places. We are started with `swfuploader` in few places, But now we found an issue that it does not work if the flash player not installed in the browser. Its working only after installed the flash player in browser. This is really worrying. We should not force user to install flash player to upload images/video. How to handle this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously your issue is solved by not using swf uploader.

My preference is [blueimp](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) project. But since you didn't mention any specific requirements in your question then regular HTML file input should work: `<input type="file"/>`

Comment: We can use normal upload, but we multiple image upload too.

Comment: @LearneR, as I said blueimp is my choice for multiple file uploads without page reload.

Comment: Ok let we try `blueimp`. Thanks for the link. Accepted :-)

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/p/upload-at-click/ < this says no flash and does uploading I would give it a look over it also points to this if you're using jQuery http://code.google.com/p/ocupload/ I personally have experience with neither (more of an AS3 background thus far) but let me know if those help.

Answer (score 1):

Its depend upon whether you required a multiple file upload or single file upload.Points needs to consider.

1. Multiple file upload with SWF - will  supported by all the browser those are installed with flash player.
2. Without the SWF file, whatever the file upload plugins developed by jquery or javascript wont support multiple file uploads in lower versions of IE.

So if you want multiple file upload in all the browsers, my suggestion is go with swf player otherwise choose the plugins without SWF.

Comment: we do have single and multiple upload